# Django Admin - Cannot delete certain users

Tags: django, django-admin, gunicorn

When I use django admin to delete some users, it returns this error:

```
ERROR base handle_uncaught_exception Internal Server Error: /admin/auth/user/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 235, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/middleware.py", line 44, in process_response
    parser=parser)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 46, in html_minify
    mini_soup = space_minify(soup, ignore_comments)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 69, in space_minify
    space_minify(child, ignore_comments)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 69, in space_minify
    space_minify(child, ignore_comments)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 69, in space_minify
    space_minify(child, ignore_comments)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 69, in space_minify
    space_minify(child, ignore_comments)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 69, in space_minify
    space_minify(child, ignore_comments)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 69, in space_minify
    space_minify(child, ignore_comments)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 69, in space_minify
    space_minify(child, ignore_comments)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 69, in space_minify
    space_minify(child, ignore_comments)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/htmlmin/minify.py", line 101, in space_minify
    soup.string.replace_with(new_string)
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 231, in replace_with
    self.extract()
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 258, in extract
    del self.parent.contents[self.parent.index(self)]
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 938, in index
    for i, child in enumerate(self.contents):
  File "/home/yuanyin/.virtualenvs/transcats/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 192, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

But get this: it doesn't appear all the time. When I try to delete some users, it doesn't show up; it appears when I try to delete others. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

`gunicorn` might be aborting a very long request.  Try setting [`--timeout`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout) to a higher value.